path_constraints vs trajectory_constraints in motion_plan_request 2024
I am wondering the same question asked here in the old ROS answers forums:
What is the difference between path_constraints and trajectory_constraints in the MotionPlanRequest message?
The answer there suggested trajectory_constraints was new and had not yet been clearly defined and to always use path_constraints, but that was way back in 2020, so I would think that maybe it was defined by now? Unless everyone has pretty much abandoned moveIt in noetic and has switched completely to ROS2.
I don't think that the question got moved to this new forum or I would have commented there.
